# QAction triggered signal is not passing checked parameter

Tags: python, parameters, pyqt, pyside, signals-slots

I have made a menu bar with a `QAction` which is set to checkable

```
self.display_features_action = QtGui.QAction("Show Features", parent)
self.display_features_action.setCheckable(True)
self.display_features_action.setChecked(True)
```

Then I connect to this

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(....)
         ....
         self.display_features_action.triggered.connect(self.my_slot)

    def my_slot(self, checked)
         ....
```

But I get a runtime error that the my_slot method takes to arguments, when only one is supplied. Why isnt the checked parameter sent with the signal?

Comment: If you are interested in the checked state, maybe you also want to use `toggled(checked)` although there are subtle differences to triggered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the treatment of signals with default parameters (such as `triggered` and `clicked`) is different in PySide to what it is in PyQt. The former won't allow any positional arguments in the receiving slot, but the latter will happily throw away unused parameters without complaint.

In both PySide and PyQt, signals with default parameters effectively have two overloads: a "no-op" version which sends nothing (or, in PyQt, always sends `False`), and an "active" version, which sends the current checked state.

The "no-op" version is the default, so to get the "active" version, you have to explicitly select it, like this:

```
    action.triggered[bool].connect(slot)
```

As for the slot signature: in PySide, the most robust solution would probably be this:

```
    def slot(self, checked=False):
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this behavior. I also see that the checked parameter is not passed.

The [documentation](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QAction.html?highlight=qaction#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QAction.triggered) of `QAction.triggered` has a default (`checked=False`) argument. Maybe that means that sometimes the signal is called without and extra argument and then checked should be false.

On the other hand I made a small example and found that there is never an extra argument, although checked should be True occasionally (if it's checked) and the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html#triggered) also says it should.

So I guess the best way is to remove that checked argument and if you need it call `isChecked`:

```
def my_slot(self, checked=False) # just in case there is an argument
   # just to be sure you really find out if it is checked, store the action and ask
   checked = self.action.isChecked()
```

My example which showed that particular behavior (PySide 1.2.2 on Python 3.4):

```
from PySide import QtGui

def test(checked=False):
    print(checked, a.isChecked())

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

t = QtGui.QToolBar()
a = QtGui.QAction('Action', t)
a.setCheckable(True)
a.setChecked(True)
a.triggered.connect(test)
t.addAction(a)
t.show()

app.exec_()
```

delivers

```
False False
False True
```